# Google stackdriver monitoring agent behind firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-vpc

I have a Google compute engine vm ubuntu host with stackdriver monitoring agent installed.

The vm host has a VPC firewall rule to deny all communication apart from a proxy server (to get system updates) and it has only an internal IP.
I have configured the stack driver agent according to doc's at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent.

The monitoring agent is unable to send monitor data to stackdriver unless i turn off the firewall rule.
What changes should i make to the VPC firewall rule in order for the agent to able to send data to stackdriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackdriver uses HTTPS to communicate with the Google API endpoints.

However, if your VM only has private IP addresses, you must also configure Private Google Access. I cover the requirements in this article:

https://www.jhanley.com/google-compute-stackdriver-logging-installation-setup-debugging/

These endpoints must be reachable for Stackdriver logging and monitoring to function:

- oauth2.googleapis.com
- monitoring.googleapis.com
- stackdriver.googleapis.com